# How to interrupt CCScrollView 's setContentOffsetInDuration()?

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

In order to slide and show contents of my `CCScrollView`, I called

```
ScrollView::setContentOffsetInDuration(Vec2 offset, float dt)
```

and according to the code, it scheduled a `MoveTo` action.

But in some context I need to interrupt and cancel the action, can anyone tells me how to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found a [solution](http://www.cocoachina.com/bbs/read.php?tid=203009). Use

```
ScrollView::getContainer()->stopAllActions()
```

works well for me :)